# php Bangla unicode outpur roman text

Tags: php, unicode

I have url like: http://localhost/site/আমার%20সোনার%20বাংলা

and I want to create a navigation like: site/আমার%20সোনার%20বাংলা

with following function-

```
function get_navig(){
 $requestURI = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$scriptName = explode('/',$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);

for ($i= 0; $i < sizeof($scriptName); $i++){
    if ($requestURI[$i] == $scriptName[$i]){
        unset($requestURI[$i]);
    }
}
$requestURI = array_values(array_filter($requestURI));
$bs=get_base_site();
if(count($requestURI)>0){
    $nav_url='<a href="'.$bs.'">'.$scriptName[1].'</a>';
}else{
    $nav_url='';
}
$nav=$scriptName[1];
foreach($requestURI as $s){
    $nav=$nav. "/".$s;
    $nav_url=$nav_url.sprintf('<a href="/%s">/%s</a>',$nav,$s);
}
return $nav_url;
```

}

it works fine except except the following output I see in my site:
site/%E0%A6%86%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%20%E0%A6%B8%E0%A7%8B%E0%A6%A8%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%20%E0%A6%AC%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%82%E0%A6%B2%E0%A6%BE

its clickable and the url works fine. moreover, when I take the cursor over this text, url shows bangla text correctly in browser's status bar.

only thing I need to correct is the text that showing in my webpage. it also works fine for English text.

anyone can help?

Comment: You've failed to encode the URL properly but the browser is fixing the error for you. You can generate proper URLs at once with `rawurlencode()`.

Comment: Thanks. i am getting desired text using rawurldecode(). it was that simple.